# Docker compose wont run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

[image]

Am I missing something?

Running the docker compose command seem self explanatory but its telling me the docker-compsose.yaml file is not there when it obviously is.

I expected the docker compose file to run the two containers.

Comment: Can you show your file structure and the contents of docker compose?

Comment: why your file is a executable file, looks a little weird

Comment: what do you mean by structure?

Comment: try this way....
docker-compose -f /path/to/docker-compose.yaml up

Comment: Sort of just a guess, but I suspect snap or some other sandboxing is preventing you from reading /. Because well, it should, what you're doing looks kind of crazy. Try doing the same from root's home folder, or better yet, not as root?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: root@MongoDB:~# docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml 
/snap/docker/2746/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:32: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography (40.0) will be the last to support Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Define and run multi-container applications with Docker.

Usage:
  docker-compose [-f <arg>...] [--profile <name>...] [options] [--] [COMMAND] [ARGS...]
  docker-compose -h|--he